# Sufficient Condition for Paracompactness

Tags: general-topology

I know that the following result is true-
If $X$ is a Hausdorff space such that $X$ is a countable union of compact sets $K_i$ such that $K_n$ is contained in the interior of $K_{n+1}$ for every n , then $X$ is paracompact.
I wonder if this result still holds good if we remove the Hausdorff condition on $X$.Can somebody please help me with a counterexample(I hope that it is false) or a proof of this statement?
Thanks for any help.

Comment: How can you contradict the definition??

Comment: I am sorry,but I don't understand your question?Please elaborate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Completely revised.**

Let $D$ be an uncountable set, and let Let $X=D\cup\{p_n:n\in\Bbb N\}$, where the points $p_n$ are distinct and not in $D$. Points of $D$ are isolated. For each finite $F\subseteq D$ the sets $B(n,F)=\{p_n\}\cup(D\setminus F)$ are a local base of open sets at $p_n$. (In other words, $\{p_n\}\cup D$ is the one-point compactification of the discrete space $D$ for each $n\in\Bbb N$.) For $n\in\Bbb N$ let

$$K_n=D\cup\{p_k:k\le n\}\;$$

clearly $K_n$ is compact and open in $X$, so $K_n\subseteq K_{n+1}=\operatorname{cl}K_{n+1}$ for each $n\in\Bbb N$.

However, $X$ is not paracompact. For $n\in\Bbb N$ let $U_n=B(n,\varnothing)$, and let $\mathscr{U}=\{U_n:n\in\Bbb N\}$; clearly $\mathscr{U}$ is an open cover of $X$. Let $\mathscr{V}$ be any open refinement of $\mathscr{U}$. For each $n\in\Bbb N$ there must be a $V_n\in\mathscr{V}$ and a finite $F_n\subseteq D$ such that $B(n,F_n)\subseteq V_n\subseteq U_n$. Let $F=\bigcup_{n\in\Bbb N}F_n$; $F$ is countable, so we may choose $x\in D\setminus F$. Clearly $x\in V_n$ for each $n\in\Bbb N$, and the sets $V_n$ are necessarily distinct, so $\mathscr{V}$ isn’t even point-finite.

Comment: In the proof when it is Hausdorff we use the fact that the K_n's are closed which we cannot use in this case,so that proof does not work here.

Comment: @Ester: Ah, you’re right. I was thinking of a version of the theorem in which the $K_n$ are assumed to be closed as well as compact and didn’t notice that you weren’t assuming that. Let me know when you’ve seen this comment, and I’ll delete the answer and think about it a bit.

Comment: It's ok and I strongly believe that the statement is not true and I also think that the counterexample will be quite tedious to find.

Comment: @Ester: You’re half right: it’s not true — the space need not even be metacompact — but the example wasn’t too hard after all.